# Google Search Console Dropped to 0 Pages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engine-indexing

I currently have 40 valid URLs on my website and my sitemap matches that. I have updated my sitemap so that I remove any unnecessary URLs (5000 URLs back to 40).

I uploaded the sitemap again to the search console and for a few days, it was showing as **0 submitted and indexed.**
[image]

Then a few days ago, google index 22 of the 40 pages,

But now, it's back to 0.

There are no errors.
Sitemap shows success but can't click on the "see index coverage" button

[image]

Also all of this started happening suddenly, I started to get impressions and click but then this happened,

When I search for my website site:somethignxyz.com it just shows me 3-4 pages which are no longer in sitemap but not shows the one that are on the website for so long.

The **mobile coverage is showing 1 valid page** (all pages are mobile friendly, I have tested them individually)

[image]

Comment: How did you handle those 5000 URLs on your site?  Do they now redirect?  Do they show errors?  Is there still an unnecessary page there?

Comment: What type of property do you have in Google Search Console?  Prefix, domain, or multiple prefix properties?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I checked that I have a "Domain Property" in there. Is that correct?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller The 5K URLs were all pointing to a single page, dynamically generated , when the issue happened, I thought it's because of them and thought that google is thinking of that as duplicate and spammy content. so I removed the pages entirely (will be 404 now)

Comment: I have the same issue... did you ever figure out a fix?  I have a sudden dropoff of "good URLs" to almost 0 and no URLs in "desktop" Core Web Vitals in any category, good, bad or needs improvement - all 0.